# How to apply a modifier in Python, creating a new mesh?

Tags: python, blender

Let's say I have a bpy.types.Object containing a bpy.types.Mesh data field; how can I apply one of the modifiers associated with the object, in order to obtain a NEW bpy.types.Mesh, possibly contained within a NEW bpy.types.Object, thus leaving the original scene unchaged?

I'm interested in applying the EdgeSplit modifier right before exporting vertex data to my custom format; the reason why I want to do this is to have Blender automatically and transparently duplicate the vertices shared by two faces with very different orientations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you're using the 2.6 API.

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply (modifier='EdgeSplit')
```

...applies to the currently active object its Edge Split modifier. Note that it's **object**.modifier_apply (...)

You can use

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = my_object
```

to set the active object. Note that it's **objects**.active.

Also, check the [modifier_apply docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_63_14/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply). Lot's of stuff you can only do with bpy.ops.*.

**EDIT:** Just saw you need a new (presumably temporary) mesh object. Just do

```
bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
```

after you set the active object and the new active object then becomes the duplicate (it retains any added modifier; if it was an object named 'Cube', it duplicates it, makes it active and names it 'Cube.001') to which you can then apply the modifier. Hope this was clear enough :)

**EDIT:** Note, that [bpy.ops.object.duplicate()](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_57_release/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.duplicate) uses not **active** object, but **selected**. To ensure the correct object is selected and duplicated do this

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
object.select = True
```

Answer (score 9):

There is another way, which seems better suited for custom exporters: Call the `to_mesh` method on the object you want to export. It gives you a copy of the object's mesh with all the modifiers applied. Use it like this:

```
mesh = your_object.to_mesh(scene = bpy.context.scene, apply_modifiers = True, settings = 'PREVIEW')
```

Then use the returned mesh to write any data you need into your custom format. The original object (including it's data) will stay unchanged and the returned mesh can be discarded after the export is finished.

Check [the Blender Python API Docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_63_14/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=object#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh) for more info.

There is one possible issue with this method. I'm not sure you can use it to apply only one specific modifier, if you have more than one defined. It seems to apply all of them, so it might not be useful in your case.

Comment: It doesn't completely apply to my case but I can probably modify my code to be compatible with the technique you describe. The main issue is that I don't want to apply the Armature modifier, because I'm exporting Actions and FCurves. But, I'm also exporting shape keys, and I recently learned that since they don't include normal information, it is basically necessary to use to_mesh. Since I'm doing armature.pose_position = 'REST' anyway at some point in my code, maybe I could use to_mesh and apply also the Armature modifier and be ok with the result. I'll think about that. Thank you :-)